# Parse and reformat a datetime string

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting, text-parsing

I have a string sent from database, I want to turn it into a date/time string. The source string is:

```
20110524153631
```

I want it to be:

```
2011-05-24 15:36:31
```

I know I can use multiple inserts but I want to know whether there's a more easy way to do this. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 you can use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) method (or its `date_create_from_format()` alias).

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'YmdHis',
    '20110524153631'
)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

For earlier versions (why?) you could play around with the string in any number of boring, or fanciful, ways.

```
vprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", sscanf("20110524153631", "%4s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s"));
```

Comment: Lots of great answers but I choose this one because its `createFromFormat` is what I wanted (also answered by onteria_) but it also covers earlier versions of PHP. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing that, we can use [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functionality to parse the date for us:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '20110524153631');
echo "This date is: " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$ php test.php
This date is: 2011-05-24 15:36:31
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$in = '20110524153631';
list(
    $year,
    $month,
    $day,
    $hour,
    $minute,
    $second) = sscanf($in, '%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d');
echo sprintf('%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d',
    $year,
    $month,
    $day,
    $hour,
    $minute,
    $second);
```

Comment: This will not give the expected output for date/time parts less than 10.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.  This unexplained answer is not as elegant as salathe's answer.  Though I do like that you are using `%d` instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '20110524153631';
echo preg_replace("/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/", "\$1-\$2-\$3 \$4:\$5:\$6", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

A possibility:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/',
         '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6', '20110524153631');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date in the SELECT or INSERT query?

Comment: This is not a normal database. I said database to simplify the question. To change this format I would have to change about 2K lines of code :D